# SBJSON parsing NSString to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdictionary, sbjson

I'm trying to parse an NSString that contains JSON data into an NSDictionary using SBJson 3.0.4, but when I do it, I get this error:

> "WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate:  -[__NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6ab7a40"

As far as I know (which isn't very far), the JSON I'm getting is valid, so I don't know why this is happening. My code compiles fine too… 
Here it is:

```
NSString *tempURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true",userInput.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:tempURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                        timeoutInterval:30];
// fetch the JSON response
NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

// make the synchronous request
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
                                returningResponse:&response 
                                            error:&error];

// construct a String around the Data from the response
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *feed = [data JSONValue];
```

Comment: Print the value of the string `data`. Copy the contents of data into the tool at JSONLint.com and see if it's valid JSON. Let us know what happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The important part of the error message is this:

```
-[__NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6ab7a40
```

The `__NSCFString` class is the private implementation class for the `NSString` interface, so you can just pretend it says `NSString`.

So we see that you are sending the `JSONValue` message to an `NSString`, and the `NSString` says it doesn't recognize that selector.  The SBJson library adds a `JSONValue` method to the `NSString` class [using a category](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/blob/master/Classes/NSObject%2BSBJson.h).

So I deduce that you haven't linked `NSObject+SBJson.o` into your app.  If you copied the SBJson source files into your app, make sure you copied in `NSObject+SBJson.m`, and make sure it is included in the “Compile Sources” build phase of your target.

If you built an SBJson library and are linked your app to that, you may need to add the `-ObjC` flag to your linker options, or even the `-all_load` flag.

Comment: I forgot to add it to the compile sources, but when I did that I now get two errors:
`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonWriter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NSObject+SBJson.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NSObject+SBJson.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: You need to add **all** of the SBJson `.m` files to the “Compile Sources” build phase.